# Voltage measurement using an opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog

I am trying to do the circuit analysis of the following circuit using LTspice.

[image]

1. When Vbatt crosses 5 V (switch is off all the time,) the output voltage is nearly constant at 0.931V. What causes the output to be constant at 0.931V?
2. When the opamp's input sees -0.7 V differential voltage, the output starts going  towards ground potential until 0.931 appears at the output. Is the input bias current causing the drop?
3. What's the purpose of using D1 and D2 in the circuit?

Comment: Weird behavior if opamp supply are (V+, 0). Seem "ok" when (+5,-5).

Comment: @Antonio51 Is opamp's output trying to pull inverting node voltage as low as possible to cope with non-inverting 1.22V but can  only go till 0.931V  and not beyond that ? is this understanding right of voltage being constant at 0.931V?

Comment: OP07 does not allow the output voltage to go lower because saturated near the ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 0.931 V is as close as the output of that opamp will get to the negative rail. It's not a rail-to-rail opamp. If you set it up as a non-inverting buffer (connect out to -in) and sweep the voltage on the +in from -1 to the supply voltage (which you don't show, I used 15 V) you will see that it will go down to a little less than a volt above the negative supply, and a little bit less than a volt below the positive supply.

The diodes are to limit the differential input, it's not that easy to see with the way it's drawn, but they are back to back across the opamp inputs.

When not in saturation the opamp will try to force the voltages at both inputs to be equal by raising or lowering the output voltage so that the current through the feedback resistor will make the inverting input the voltage as the non-inverting input. With no voltage difference across them the diodes will not conduct. When in saturation it won't be able to maintain this condition and there may be enough voltage to cause the diodes to conduct and limit the differential voltage to around 0.7 V.

Comment: @GodJihyo , Again my question is , when i short the R3  , Vout is equal to non inverting terminal voltage  but increase in value  of R13 causes output to go towards ground rail ? what the explaination for that . Thanks

Comment: @Ronnie When you short R3, which you only mentioned in the comments, the opamp becomes a voltage follower for the ref voltage and its output just drives the node connected to the 100K resistor to the same potential.

Comment: @Ronnie When you increase R13 the gain of the circuit will increase (Rf / Ri). With higher gain the positive voltage from Vbatt will be amplified more, and since it's going into the inverting input that will drive the output lower.

Comment: @devnull , when i add the R3 with value of 13 K , it becomes a inverting amplifier ? Is that correct ?

Answer (score 3):

The diodes are to clamp the inverting input within a diode drop of Vref regardless of what the op amp is attempting to do.  If you have valid feedback, the inverting input should be within a hair of the noninverting feedback (V+=V- on first approximation).  So, it looks like the circuit is to prevent something from happening when you're asking the output of the op amp to get too close to the rails to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of this circuit is weird if opamp supplies are (V+, 0) (???).
Output Voltage Swing for RL ≥ 10 kΩ typical ±13.0 V (supply +15/-15).
So, saturated voltage ~ 2V, which is verified here.

[image]

Here is what happens when opamp supplies are (+5,-5).

[image]

As vout goes very nearest 0 V, one should use a rail to rail output opamp.

Here is the case of a rail to rail output opamp, unipolar supply. More clear.

[image]

Comment: When the R3 is shorted , output Voltage reaches to 1.225 V which is obvious . what  R3=13K  is exactly doing to keep the Vout  near to  0.9V ?

Comment: You can see now that the behavior is "logical". OP07 should not be used with a unipolar supply.

Comment: 0.9V is the saturated voltage of the OP-07. So it can't change.